# How do I move a sectioned column to the right place inside a List Page in Cognos Report Studio?

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-bi

I'm new into Cognos and I have not seen any tutorials online that would help me solve this puzzle.

How do I move a sectioned column to the right place inside a List Page in Cognos Report Studio?

My manager asked me to edit an existing report and wants me to add a new column (Underwriter Column) and put it inside a List Page.

This is the original look and feel of the report.
[image]

Then my Manager wants to add a new column and make it look like this.

[image]

So I drag the new column from the Main Query to the list page.

[image]

Then I highlight the Underwriter column and click the Section/Unsection column to add the new column below the Insured Name column.

[image]

The problem is the new column I just added after clicking section/unsection button goes between Policy Number and Questionaire Name. It should be placed below the Insured Name column (highlighted yellow line).

[image]

Is there any way to fix this? To drag the new column on the desired area?
Should I add a List inside the List Column Body of the one highlighted in the screenshot below?

[image]

As you notice that there are List Column Body inside a List Column Body that is also inside a List Column Body.

[image]

How is it possible to insert a new column (encircled in green, Figure 8) inside a List Column Body under the Insured Name List Column Body?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First create the section, then highlilght the whole List/table/page (click the top left most 3 dots) then go to main menu at the top and **DATA > SORT > EDIT LAYOUT SORTING**.

In the new dialogue box under groups, click your group and click the down arrow to move the group down the list to the desired position.

(My version is 10.2.2)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer makes sense however, this is a report where a list column body is inside a list column  body that is also inside a list column body which makes it difficult to insert the new Column "Underwriter" column because the goal is to insert the new Underwriter column to the bottom list column body. I have updated and edited my question here in stack overflow with additional screenshots in order to explain my question in a granular level.